# Why can't I do this arithmetic operation on eshell? Error: "Symbol’s function definition is void: \,"

Tags: eshell, numbers

I am trying to run a simple addition operation in `eshell`. Trying with an illustrative minimal example:

```lisp
 ~/$ (+ 1
       -4)
```

`eshell` returns:

```lisp
-3
```

Since the above operation worked out, I tried the real which is bigger:

```lisp
~/$ (+ 0
  -171.055,81 
   -826.735,77 
   -528.986,10 
   256.257,51
   97.045,11
   17.349,00
   10.755,83
   -4,03 
   505.312,10
   60.000,00
   3.827,32
   48.832,18
   907,99
   14.858,23
   131.439,91
   8.688,42
   3.483,25
   64.395,72
   -437,19 
   17.413,90
   2.017,70
   149,00
   30.612,72
   21.566,77
   17.915,59
   18.250,70
   12.780,69
   7.969,96
   1.834,31
   3.608,93
   4.107,56
   5.323,56
   49.792,66
   1.278,27
   13.524,78

   130.737,01
   7.200,00
   5.439,65
   5.463,08
   135.775,31
   20.212,66
   4.312,81
   303.029,90
   94.248,43
   -78.887,90 
   -20.212,66 
   -4.312,81 
   -297.278,33 
   -57.037,81 
   -6.003,83 
   -60.000,00 
   -12.086,73 
   -104.505,00 
   35.400,44
   -100,00 
   -49.541,92 
   44.066,93)
```

Unfortunately, it returns an error message:

> Symbol’s function definition is void: ,

What is causing this error? How can I fix the operation?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: ok, @Drew I thought this could be related to something on how Elisp was dealing with floating point numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eshell doesn’t like your numbers. It expects you to use a period for the decimal separator, and it also expects you not to use any thousands separator. Like this:

```lisp
~/$ (+ 0
   -171055.81 
   -826735.77 
   -528986.10 
   …
```

Answer (score 1):

@db48x answered your question. But see also the Elisp manual, node [Numbers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Numbers.html), and its subnodes (e.g. [Integer Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Integer-Basics.html) and [Float Basics](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Float-Basics.html)) for info on the representation (syntax) of numbers (numerals) in Elisp.

That tells you exactly what representations are allowed for numerals in Elisp.